# Dynamic Memory Management for a pointer to a pointer (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory

I need some help. I have an array of pointers:

```
int *ptr = new int[N];
```

I want a two dimensional array of pointers, which points to that one dimensional array. I know how to allocate memory for a two dimensional pointer:

```
int (*nn)[4] = new int [N][4];
```

BUT: How to allocate memory for a two dimensional pointer to a pointer? Is that possible anyway?

I need to define neighbors on a grid. Finally the connection should be like this:

```
for (int Vertex = 0; Vertex < N; ++Vertex) {
    nn[Vertex][0] = ptr[(Vertex + 1) % N];
    nn[Vertex][1] = ptr[(Vertex + N - 1)% N];
    nn[Vertex][2] = ptr[(Vertex + L) % N];
    nn[Vertex][3] = ptr[(Vertex + N - L) % N];
    if (Vertex % L == 0) {
        nn[Vertex][1] = ptr[Vertex + L - 1];
    }
    if((Vertex + 1)%L == 0){
        nn[Vertex][0] = ptr[Vertex - L + 1];
    }
}
```

I just got stuck in allocating the memory...

Comment: Try using `std::vector<std::array<T>>`.

Comment: "I have an array of pointers" No you don't. You have a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of `int`.

Comment: `int *ptr = new int[N];` - that isn't an array of pointers; its a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a two dimensional array of pointers to int, you actually need a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to int, and you need to allocate the memory in a for-loop, like this:

```
int *** nn = new int**[N];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) nn[i] = new int*[4];
```

Now nn[x][y] is a pointer to an int and *(nn[x][y]) is an int.

It is true what the comments say, though, ptr is not an array of pointers. However, you can still make nn point to the values of ptr by doing this:

```
nn[x][y] = ptr+index;
```

and NOT:

```
nn[x][y] = ptr[index];
```